# How to unit test an event subscribtion with NUnit

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, event-handling, nunit

Hi there i wonder if someone knows an answer to my question:

Consider the following code

```
class TheHandler
{
    ...
    Public EventHandler myRealWorldEvent;
    ...


}

class TheSubscriber
{
    private TheHandler myHandler = new TheHandler();

    public subscribeToHandler()
    { 
        myHandler.myRealWorldEventHandler += OnSomethingHappens;

    }

     ...

    pirvate OnSomeThingHappens()
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

My question here is -> how can i test (with NUnit only) that OnSomethingHappens got subscribed to myRealWorldEventHandler. I cannot change the SUT/production-code and i cannot Mock (Moq/Nmock etc.). Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

Best regards,

zhengtonic

Comment: You want to test that `OnSomethingHappens` gets called when `myRealWorldEvent` fires? Is it right?

Comment: I want to know if OnSomethingHappens got subscribed to myRealworldEventHandler. But yes i can fire it an test the outcome. In NMock its a Expect.Once.On(myRealworldEventHandler).EventAdd(OnSomethingHappens, Is.Anything);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NUnit doesn't do that - testing whether some *private* handler subscribed to some *private* field. There's too much private stuff involved. However, it's nothing you can't do with a little bit help from reflection. Note that it's not pretty code:

```
var subscriber = new TheSubscriber();
var handlerField = typeof(TheSubscriber)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    // if field with such name is not present, let it fail test
    .First(f => f.Name == "myHandler");

var handlerInstance = handlerField.GetValue(subscriber);
var someEventField = typeof(TheHandler)
    .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .First(f => f.Name == "myRealWorldEvent");

var eventInstance = (EventHandler) someEventField.GetValue(handlerInstance);
var subscribedMethod = eventInstance
    .GetInvocationList()
    .FirstOrDefault(d => d.Method.Name == "OnSomethingHappens");

Assert.That(subscribedMethod, Is.Not.Null);
```

If you'll have to deal with lot of legacy systems testing (ie. private members, static members - something that free frameworks don't handle well or at all) - I suggest taking a look at tools such as [TypeMock](http://www.typemock.com/isolator-product-page) or [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking/features.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Code from jimmy_keen was not working in a proper way with old .NETs. Solved it by writing helper methods:

```
public static void assertSubscribed<EventHandlerType>(object handler, object subscriber, string eventName = null) {
    var inappropriate = false;
    try {
        if (!typeof (EventHandlerType).IsSubclassOf(typeof (Delegate)) ||
            typeof (EventHandlerType).GetMethod("Invoke").ReturnType != typeof (void))
            inappropriate = true;
    } catch (AmbiguousMatchException) {
        inappropriate = true;
    } finally {
        if (inappropriate) throw new Exception("Inappropriate Delegate: " + typeof (EventHandlerType).Name);
    }

    var handlerField = subscriber.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .First(h => h.FieldType.IsInstanceOfType(handler));

    var handlerInstance = handlerField == null ? null : handlerField.GetValue(subscriber);
    var eventField = handlerInstance == null ? null : handlerInstance.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .First(f => (f.FieldType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (EventHandlerType)) &&
                     (eventName == null || eventName.Equals(f.Name))));

    var eventInstance = eventField == null ? null : (Delegate)eventField.GetValue(handlerInstance);
    var subscribedMethod = eventInstance == null
        ? null 
        :eventInstance.GetInvocationList().FirstOrDefault(
            d => d.Method.DeclaringType != null && d.Method.DeclaringType.IsInstanceOfType(subscriber));

    Assert.That(subscribedMethod, Is.Not.Null);
}
```

"Not" method:

```
public static void assertNotSubscribed<EventHandlerType>(object handler, object subscriber, string eventName = null) {
    var inappropriate = false;
    try {
        if (!typeof (EventHandlerType).IsSubclassOf(typeof (Delegate)) ||
            typeof (EventHandlerType).GetMethod("Invoke").ReturnType != typeof (void))
            inappropriate = true;
    } catch (AmbiguousMatchException) {
        inappropriate = true;
    }
    if (inappropriate) return;

    var handlerField = subscriber.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .First(h => h.FieldType.IsInstanceOfType(handler));

    var handlerInstance = handlerField == null ? null : handlerField.GetValue(subscriber);

    var eventField = handlerInstance == null ? null : handlerInstance.GetType()
        .GetFields(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .First(f => (f.FieldType.IsAssignableFrom(typeof (EventHandlerType)) &&
                     (eventName == null || eventName.Equals(f.Name))));

    var eventInstance = eventField==null?null:(Delegate) eventField.GetValue(handlerInstance);
    var subscribedMethod = eventInstance == null
        ? null
        : eventInstance.GetInvocationList().FirstOrDefault(
                d => d.Method.DeclaringType != null && d.Method.DeclaringType.IsInstanceOfType(subscriber));

    Assert.That(subscribedMethod, Is.Null);
}
```

And invocation:

```
assertSubscribed<EventHandler>(handler, subscriber);
assertNotSubscribed<EventHandler>(handler, subscriber);
assertSubscribed<EventHandler>(handler, subscriber, "myRealWorldEvent");
assertNotSubscribed<EventHandler>(handler, subscriber, "myRealWorldEvent");
```

Don't bother me for code style convention but this method looks compact enough.